# Liquid level animation( Battery Doctor )

Tags: java, android, animation, opengl-es, graphics2d

I want to know how to make this kind of animation in android ( The same in Battery Doctor app ).

[image: Animation from Battery Doctor]

I found a way to do this using two green images with an oppacity of 50% one behind the other and another one on the front to hide the unwanted content ( The circle ),I animate the first green image by XML using the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:duration="1850"
    android:fromDegrees="-4"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toDegrees="4" />
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="1"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="1500" />

</set>
```

And the second green one by using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:duration="1800"
    android:fromDegrees="-1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"

    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toDegrees="1" />
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="80"
    android:toXDelta="-4"
    android:fromYDelta="-1"
    android:toYDelta="1"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="1500" />

</set>
```

But how can I create the view programatically ?I want to set the level dynamically from code. for example myView.setLevel(45);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have finally found a library: WaveView

https://github.com/john990/WaveView

**Edit**

This library https://github.com/gelitenight/WaveView also does the same thing with more features. You can :

- Shift the wave horizontally.
- Set water level.
- Set vertical size of wave.
- Set horizontal size of wave.